# How can I write a date using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I write a date using typescript?

I select a date in the picker, and try to write it in the state, but I get an error, how to do it correctly?

```
const [dateFrom, setDateFrom] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());

onChange={(e, v) => {
  setDateFrom(v);
}}
```

> ype '(e: Date | null, v: Date | null) => void' is not assignable to
> type '(date: Date | null, value?: string | null | undefined) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'v' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date | null'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date | null'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you are not doing the proper checks on the value:

> Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date | null'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date | null'.

v could be `string`, `null`, `undefined` and you are assigning it to a variable that is `Date` or `null`. They are not compatible types.

You should <s>cast</s> create a Date in case v is a string, or assign null otherwise

```
onChange={(e, v) => {
 setDateFrom(typeof v === 'string' ? new Date(v) : null);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [dateFrom, setDateFrom] = useState<Date | undefined>(new Date());

onChange={(e, v) => {
  setDateFrom(new Date(v));
}}
```